# "ORA-00903: invalid table name" error while updating a record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table called `iowe`. It *has* been created and exists in my database. This is how it looks like:

```
NAME           AMOUNT Serial Number
---------- ---------- -------------
Praveen         20500
Roshan           5000             2
Rohit            5000             3
Shashi           7500             4
```

When I try to update the Serial Number corresponding to the name Praveen, by inputting the command

```
update table iowe
set "Serial Number" = 1 where amount = 20500
```

or

```
update table iowe
set "Serial Number" = 1 where name = 'Praveen'
```

I get the following error: `ORA-00903: invalid table name`

Other commands execute fine on this table.

Comment: Does it work, if you enter a schema? update schema.table iowe set "Serial Number" = 1 where amount = 20500

Comment: It worked without the term "table".. all i had to input was "update iowe" and not "update table iowe"

Comment: this can occur even when  the schema is null!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need the keyword `table` in an [update statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10008.htm):

```
update iowe
set "Serial Number" = 1
where amount = 20500
```

As you have it, it's looking for a table *called* `'table`', while giving it the *alias* '`iowe`'.

Not relevant to the question, but I would also really advise not giving objects mixed-case or non-standard names, since you have to quote them - as you are with `"Serial Number"`. I have yet to see a case where the added complication and opportunities for confusion can be justified.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the word "table" from your update statement:

```
update iowe
set "Serial Number" = 1 
where name = 'Praveen'
```